# Angularjs Updating Facebook og meta tags dynamically

Tags: angularjs, facebook, meta-tags, facebook-opengraph

I want to update facebook og meta tags dynamically. I found an angular service :

```
angular.module('App.Common')
.service('MetadataService', ['$window', function($window){
    var self = this;
    self.setMetaTags = function (tagData){
        $window.document.ogdescription = tagData.ogdescription;
        $window.document.ogname = tagData.ogname;
        $window.document.ogimage = tagData.ogimage;
 }; 
}]);
```

And on my template file I set it up like this:

```
<meta property="og:title" name="ogname" content=""/>
<meta property="og:description" name="ogdescription" content=""/>
<meta property="og:image" name="ogimage" content=""/>
```

And on one of my controllers:

```
angular.module('App.Common')
.controller('ArticleController', function (MetadataService){
    MetadataService.setMetaTags({
        ogname : 'some title',
        ogdescription : 'some desc',
        ogimage : 'some image'
    });
});
```

This does not update the meta tags. I dont know where I am wrong. Please pardon my english.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try by using id attribute

```
<meta property="og:title" id="ogname" content=""/>
<meta property="og:description" id="ogdescription" content=""/>
<meta property="og:image" id="ogimage" content=""/>
```

Change method like this

```
self.setMetaTags = function (tagData){
    $window.ogdescription.content = tagData.ogdescription;
    $window.ogname.content = tagData.ogname;
    $window.ogimage.content = tagData.ogimage;
};
```